# Preview of latex formulas not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I tried to [edit this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/please-help-me-remember-a-formula) to reflow the formula, and noticed that MathJax stopped rendering the latex code in preview window. I use Google Chrome 10 on Mac OS X 10.6.6 Also why does this valid formula does not render (I've checked it on TexLive-2010):

```
\begin{align*}
    -N-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N (2j-1) \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}+\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_j}
\exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)\\\\
+\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_{N-j+1}}
\exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
```

The problem is that it seems that `\left(` requires the `right)` without the line-break.

Comment: I'm marking this `[status-bydesign]` as this appears to be an issue with the MathJax code and not our renderer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow. I've pasted that TeX below and it's rendering (albeit slowly) in the preview.

\begin{align*}
    -N-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N (2j-1) \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}+\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_j}
\exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right) \
+\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_{N-j+1}}
\exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

EDIT: Probably the place to ask is the [MathJaX Users Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/). Something like this has [already been asked](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/) I guess that suggests one find another way of doing it (which you have already done and it is far more readable in my opinion).

Comment: are you able to introduce new line before the second logarithm? I've posted the same code in a separate answer with the break. It does not render.

Comment: No, I'm not that proficient with TeX. Might be a question for http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: they answer MathJax questions? As I said LaTeX renders the formula with the break just fine, the problem seems to me is with MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Hm here is my separate try, note that there should be 4 slashes, not 2:
\begin{align*}
    -N-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N (2j-1) \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}+\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_j}
\exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)\\
+\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}-\int_{\bar{x}}^{x_{N-j+1}}
\exp\left(-\frac{(t-\bar{x})^2}{2s^2}\right)\mathrm{dt}\right)\right)
\end{align*}